# Drupal Filter View IF Field match Current Domain

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view

What is the best way to achieve this? I've tried tokens, they don't work, only in the URL to get results when you land the VIEW.

leads?dm=[current-domain:hostname]

I am passing current domain to filter content of a view from the URL ( dm = domain ) The way it currently works is that I have a table of webform submitted values, each submission has a field ( Domain ) I need the results to show only rows where field "Domain" match current domain.

This works: leads?dm=[current-domain:hostname] BUT once the reset button is clicked then that Filter disappears ( exposed filter hidden with css ) but I need to set ( Current Domain Value ) to it as default so it never shows fields with other domains...unless you are in other domain - I am using Domain Access and the latest version of Views and Token.

I created a Filter:

Configure filter criterion: Webform submission data: Data field ( dm ) Equals= Value but token doesn't work.

I will really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use contextual filters under the advanced section.

Select your field like you would do in the normal filter section, in the config page that follows select "Provide default value" if you are storing the domain id in the webform then you can select "Current domain" if you are storing the machine name of the domain select "Php Code" to filter your results with the following code:

```
$domainGet = domain_get_domain();
$domain = $domainGet['machine_name'];
return $domain;
```